# SSLv2 required on TLS-only site?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, tls

This problem has been driving me crazy for a very long time. We have three web servers, serving East, West and Central offices. We built the Central server first, imaged it, and copied the image to the other two sites after we passed the internal Security scan and ensured we were FIPS 140-2 compliant. The servers are running Windows 2008 Standard R2, IIS 7.5, and are as close to identical as their respective environments will allow. All three web servers are restricted to https on port 443. Each server's certificate was generated using the same certificate authority and encryption algorithms.

Our users are able to connect just fine to East and Central. But when they access West, some -- not all, but some -- are unable to connect unless they enable SSL 2.0. Most of our users have a standard setup on their workstations and laptops: Windows 7, IE8. Since it doesn't happen to everybody, and those same users who can't get into West have no trouble with the others, it doesn't feel like a client issue to me.

SSL 2.0 is NOT enabled on any of the servers. Only TLS is enabled -- no version of SSL is enabled on any of the servers, not even 3.0. I've run diagnostic software to check the ciphers that are installed, and they come back affirming that SSL 2.0 is NOT running on the server. I've even run practical tests: I've disabled TLS in my browser and attempted to connect using SSL 2.0, 3.0 or both. My connection is refused, as it should be. I also ran a couple of network sniffers from my location, before IT detected me and shut me off... and they confirmed that SSL 2.0 is disabled.

I thought that an encrypted connection had to be direct and unmodified in order to stay secure. But could there be something on the network between our server and the client request -- a bad proxy, for example -- that is somehow interfering with the connection in certain cases?

If anybody has any advice, I'd appreciate hearing it. I'm at my wits' end.

(Please note I'm not based at any of the three locations, and I have no direct access to the network infrastructure for diagnostics. I have to *know* the specific problem I want to solve before I dare approach IT. Anyway, thanks in advance!)

Comment: Are their connections actually using SSLv2?  Can you get a packet capture run on a system having the issue to verify?  Any maybe more information about the network infrastructure there?  A proxy could potentially cause problems, as could something doing protocol inspection and dropping the connections, like a firewall.. but unless you know what's actually happening, we're kinda grasping at straws.

Comment: I would recheck the system again, maybe your scanner is malfunctioning. Try using a third party website to test like this one: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Comment: Shane -- Thanks! I've requested more information from the network folks at West, but all I've received so far is a couple of log extracts showing _some_ connections are getting through (which I already knew). I will try to ask for some more details, if you think a proxy might indeed interfere with the SSL connection.

Comment: BadDos -- Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, our access to sites like that is blocked by policy. I've had to rely on what I could run internally (until IT shuts me down!). I have, however, checked using more than one tool, since I agree that a bad scan is very possible. But we _did_ pass FIPS compliance scanning early on, so I'm inclined to think the likelihood of bad scans is relatively low.